# Using each plugin in Nutch separately

Tags: plugins, nutch, extractor

I'm using ***extractor*** plugin with **Nutch-1.15**. The plugin makes use of *parsed data*.

The plugin works fine when used as a whole. The problem arises when a few changes are made to the *custom-extractos.xml* file.

The entire crawling process needs to be restarted even if there is a small change in the *custom-extractors.xml* file.

Is there a way that single plugin can be used separately on parsed data?

Answer (score 0):

Since this plugin is a Parser filter, it must be used as part of the Parse step, and is not stand-alone.

However, there are a number of things you can do.

If you are looking to change the configuration on the fly (only affecting newly parsed documents), you can use the [extractor.file](https://github.com/BayanGroup/nutch-custom-search#setup) property to specify any location on the HDFS, and replace this file as needed, it will be read by each task.

If you are want to reapply the changes to previously parsed documents, the answer is dependent on the specifics of your crawl, but you may be able to run the parse step again using `nutch parse` on old segments (you will need to delete the existing parse folders in the segments).

Comment: I wanted to apply the changes to already crawled documents. I deleted the parse directories and reparsed it. It works like magic. Thanks a ton. I have another question though. Are ALL the plugins in Nutch used after the "Fetch" step? If so, any changes to plugin related documents can be reflected in the data by just reparsing, isn't it?

Comment: The general answer is "No". Parse filter plugins are all applied in the parse step, but there are also other type of plugins that apply in other steps. Scoring plugins, for example, are used in many steps, including generate.